# Oracle Query: How to get the most recent Active Record from this Log Table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have below ServerKeyLog Table to track all the Key changes at the server level.
Now corresponding to selected Date Range, I need to retrieve the most recent Publish Date record for each KeyId if it's IsActive Flag = 'T'. 
If the most recent IsActive Flag = 'F' for any Key, we don't need to retrieve that Key.

Appreciate your time.

[image]

Comment: could you post the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your date range is anything in the month of August, you can do it like this:

```
select *
 from (select skl.*,
              row_number() over (partition by skl.KeyId order by skl.PublishDate desc) as rn
         from ServerKeyLog skl
        where skl.PublishDate >= date '2015-08-01'
          and skl.PublishDate < date '2015-09-01')
where rn = 1
  and IsActive = 'T'
order by KeyId
```

Answer (score 2):

To get all info about IDs with up-recent ISACTIVE = T use the following query:

```
select *
  from SERVERKEYLOG T1
 WHERE (PUBLISHDATE, KEYID) IN
       (SELECT MAX(PUBLISHDATE) RECENT, KEYID
          FROM SERVERKEYLOG
         GROUP BY KEYID)
   AND T1.ISACTIVE = 'T'
```